# CakePHP: Error: Database table cake_errors for model CakeError was not found

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP error and I having a hard time to trace the problem. Hope you can help me.
Here is the error message:

```
Missing Database Table
Error: Database table cake_errors for model CakeError was not found.
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_table.ctp
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in Advance.

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: From where and how are you calling CakeError?

Comment: What is the controller/action that led to this error message?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell why exactly without seeing the code firsthand, one trick i have used with theese kinds of errors though is making "app/views/errors/missing_table.ctp" as inserting the following code

```
<?php pr( Debugger::trace() ); ?>
```

This will will help workout what you called to cause this issue in the first place.

Comment: My officemate figured out the problem. He just added a cake_error table in the database and just worked. Problem solved. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is 4 years old, but since I bumped into the exact same problem and found no information about it that could explain where the error is coming from, I did some digging of my own and come up with some clues that I include here in case it helps.

My AppController beforeFiler() method, amongst other things, uses a function that checks if the Model of the Controller has enum fields (I know... I know...) and handles them "properly".

When an error in the application triggers an Exception (Nothing fancy... a "Missing Controller" does it) and the debug level is 0, the CakeErrorController tries to render the exception and it fails because there's no cake_errors table, generating an endless loop that ends when PHP runs out of memory.

I fixed this by improving the detection of whether the main Model of the controller is indeed using a "real" table.